# Preload webfonts with format/url variants?

Tags: page-speed, fonts, link-prefetching

PageSpeed Insights complains that I should preload important assets, which I already do for CSS (http header `Link: </assets/css/myfile.css>; rel=preload; as=style`).
However, the complaints are specifically about web fonts. Indeed, these can currently download only after the (preloaded) CSS has been downloaded. The problem is that these fonts come in various variants (myfont.eot, myfont.svg, myfont.woff, myfont.woff2) and it is up to the client t decide which to download:

```
@font-face{
 font-family:myfont;
 src:url(/assets/font/myfont.eot);
 src:url(/assets/font/myfont.eot) format('embedded-opentype'),
     url(/assets/font/myfont.woff) format('woff'),
     url(/assets/font/myfont.woff2) format('woff2'),
     url(/assets/font/myfont.svg) format('svg');
 ...
```

So if I specifically preload the variant PageSpped Insights complains about, I make them happy but cause superfluous download for any client with a different font format preference.

**Q:** Is there any way to make a "variant-aware preload", i.e., instead of "download this file, you will probably need it in a moment, trust me" something like "download one of these files, whichever has the format you'd prefer for a font in case you need it later"?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to provide so many formats for your fonts these days.   It looks the woff format is universally supported https://caniuse.com/?search=woff   Only Opera Mini doesn't support it, and that browser doesn't appear to support *any* web font formats.   If you drop support for IE 11, you could use woff2.